# "Cannot get password" error - Connecting PostgresQL with VS Code

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, passwords, database-connection

I'm new with PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to add a connection using the extension PostgreSQL by Chris Kolkman, the error mentioned cannot get password on the lower right of VS code.

[here's the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YjLU.png)

Comment: Well, should it need a password?  If so, how should it get it?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on MacOS, you need to go into your keychain access and look for `ckolkman.vscode-postgres`. Delete the entries for this app and then reload your Postgres extension.

Comment: On Linux I found a similar application under GNOME called "Passwords and Keys" in which I could delete the invalid passwords causing VS Code to choke with the error message "Unable to parse decrypted password". 

You still need to delete all Postgress connections using a password afterwards, but you do avoid having to delete the entire `~/.config/Code` directory.

Answer (score 0):

After some update, i have same problem on Linux (Ubuntu).
I remove folder `~/.config/Code` and reinstall **VSCode**.
This solved my problem. I hope it will be helpful